# Отключение 3,3v

Tags: c, arduino

Можно ли программно отключить питание (на время, а потом снова подать) на ножке 3,3v. Тем самым сделать ресет всем периферийным устройствам питающимся с этой ножки.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию

Comment: @Abyx, судя по ответу (тому, который именно про периферию), таки не имеет.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы сбросить подключенные модули (например, шилды), потребуется добавить цепь холодного сброса. С её помощью можно будет "нажимать кнопку сброса", устанавливая в логическую 1 один из выводов микроконтроллера. Вопрос лишь в том, что микроконтроллер ATmega управляется инверсным сигналом NRESET. То есть при логическом 0 микроконтроллер находится в состоянии сброса. То есть сигнал сброса нужно инвертировать. Чтобы реализовать эту логику, потребуется 1 транзистор и 1 резистор. Схему и пример скетча см. [здесь](http://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/arduino-tips-and-tricks#p14). [image: Схема холодного сброса Arduino]

Comment: Нужно, чтобы в ответе было больше, чем просто ссылка. Пожалуйста, продублируйте здесь хотя бы основные пункты решения. Кстати, если даёте ссылку на свой сайт или блог, то принято об этом явно сообщать.

Comment: А вообще, добро пожаловать ) У нас мало специалистов по Arduino тут.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте реализовать [программную перезагрузку Arduino c помощью функции reset](http://arduino-diy.com/arduino-perezagruzit-na-programmnom-urovne), если в вашем случае можно позволить себе перезагружать и отрабатывать скетч заново.

Comment: На сколько понял, автору надо перегрузить только периферийные устройства.